# Is ther a way to determine Length of signal in computing the spectrogram for a specific size

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

Is there a way to determine the length of the signal and window size that should be used to create a spectrogram of a user specified dimension `x*y` ? For example, in order to create spectrogram of size `100*100`, the length of the signal is `N=80050` and `w = 80` . I have produced spectrogram of a signal using matlab like this:

```
N = 80050;
w = 80;
signal = randn(1,N);
  spec=spectrogram(signal,w,0,256);
  specto= spec(1:100,1:100);
  specto_power=(20*log10(abs(specto)));
specMin_1 = min(specto_power(:));
specMax_1 = max(specto_power(:));

figure(1)
pcolor(specto_power)
caxis([specMin_1 specMax_1])
shading flat
pcolor(specto_power)
caxis([specMin_1 specMax_1])
shading flat
```

How do I determine `N` and the window size `w` to generate different spectrograms of different dimensions say `40*40`, `50*50` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the signal and window lengths, another tuning knob available to you is the step (or "hop") between successive segments in the spectrogram analysis, which also plays a part in how many frames of output are computed. In [Matlab's spectrogram function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html), the step is determined by the `noverlap` arg, related by `noverlap = w - step`.
For signal length `N`, window length `w`, and step `step`, the number of frames (columns) in the spectrogram is

```
# frames = floor((N - w) / step) + 1
```

(E.g. there is one frame if N == w; two frames if N == w + step; etc.)

In the other dimension, the number of frequencies in the spectrogram relates to the FFT size argument, `nfft`. The spectrum of a real signal has complex conjugate (Hermitian) symmetry, so about half the bins are redundant. The redundant bins are usually excluded from a spectrogram. Assuming this is done, the number of frequencies (rows) in the spectrogram is

```
# frequencies = floor(nfft / 2) + 1
```

To generate spectrograms specific sizes, we can work the above formulas backward as

```
N = w + ((# frames) - 1) * step,
nfft = 2 * ((# frequencies) - 1).
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I am unable to follow how to apply these formula for my problem. In my case I know the sizes of the spectrogram. So in the formula for N and w where do I input the size value? Can you please elaborate a bit more?If `nooverlap` is true,, then in my question the line containing spectrogram() function will have `step=0` in my `spectrogram()` input. Then the `N` value does not match for `100*100` size output spectrogram. I am confused.

Comment: In my example, `nooverlap =0`, so what is the value of `step`? Can you please show with an example with any arbitrary spectrogram size how `N` is determined.

Comment: If I apply the formula, then in order to create a spectrogram of size `size = 40*40` using `N = 200;`
`size = 40;`
`step  = 1;`
`w= N-(size-1)*step  = 78;`

  
 `nfft= 2 * (size - 1);` ( # frequencies = rows = size = 40)

 `specto=spectrogram(signal,w,0,nfft);` does not give an output of size 40 by 40.

Comment: The `w = N-(size-1)*step` in your example should be 161, not 78. Also, the third arg to `spectrogram` should be `noverlap` which is `w - step = 160`, not 0. Try N = 200, w = 161, noverlap = 160, nfft = 78.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Last clarification: if the third argument to `spectrogram` is 0 as I wrote in my question then it does not mean that overalap = 0? By default `nooverlap=50%`, so if I pass a value 0 then what is the value of `nooverlap` that I should take ?

Comment: Glad it works! =) The third arg is not "no overlap" but "noverlap", and it specifies the number of overlapping samples between one segment and the next (see [spectrogram's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html)). If you pass noverlap = 0 for the third arg, then step = w and the segments don't overlap at all. Or if you pass noverlap = w - 1, then step = 1 and a segment overlaps completely, except for it's rightmost sample, with the previous segment.